# c++ type cast an arithmetic operation

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>

 int main()
 {
     long long w_popn;
     long long us_popn;
     std::cout << "Enter the world's population: ";
     std::cin >> w_popn;
     std::cout << "Enter the population of the US: ";
     std::cin >> us_popn;
     std::cout << "The population of the US is " << float (us_popn/w_popn) << "% of the world population" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

I am currently doing some exercise questions from c++ primer plus, and I am stuck at the very last print statement in my code. Particularly the part where I type **float (us_popn/w_popn)**. Is there a quick and dirty way of turning the  results into a floating number in the cout statement without having to manually store the results in a float variable? I ask this because it seems that putting a typecast of float in front of the integer division in a cout statement doesn't seem to affect it and I end up getting 0 as a result of truncation.

Comment: Try this `float(us_popn)/w_popn`. You're type casting the result of dividing two integers into `float` which is useless, you've to cast _before_ the operation happens, so that both operands would then be `float`s thereby yielding a floating-point result.

Comment: I would recomend not to use (float)x/y, but to use x/(float)y, this exactly states that you are doing float point division and logically more precise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the operands before the division, otherwise you will be casting the result:

```
static_cast<float>(us_popn)/static_cast<float>(w_popn)
```